# Google Vis Dashboard with a working ready listener

Tags: google-visualization, dashboard

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Dashboard Evelien</title>
    <!--Load the AJAX API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      // Load the Visualization API and the controls package.
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart', 'controls', 'table']});

      // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawDashboard);

      // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
      // instantiates a dashboard, a range slider and a pie chart,
      // passes in the data and draws it.
      function drawDashboard() {

        // Create our data table.
 var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['geo_Stad',               'Name', 'Leningdelen', 'Hypotheek',           'Straat', 'Woonplaats',          'Datum_start',          'Datum_eind', 'Mv', 'looptijd'],
          ['Netherlands, Amsterdam', 'Aap' ,             5,      500000,     'Kalverstraat',  'Amsterdam', new Date(2014,  3, 22), new Date(2016,  2, 28), 'm', 123], 
          ['Netherlands, Rotterdam', 'Noot',             1,       70000,       'Beursplein',  'Rotterdam', new Date(2014, 10, 11), new Date(2017,  3, 20), 'm', 234],
          ['Netherlands, Rotterdam', 'Mies',             3,      300000,    'Stationsplein',  'Rotterdam', new Date(2013, 10,  1), new Date(2013, 12, 23), 'v', 564],
          ['Netherlands, Amsterdam', 'Wim' ,             2,      222222,      'Dorpsstraat',  'Amsterdam', new Date(2010,  1,  2), new Date(2016, 10, 23), 'm', 456],
          ['Netherlands, Amsterdam', 'Zus' ,             7,      600000,    'Stationsplein',  'Amsterdam', new Date(2007,  5, 22), new Date(2009,  2,  2), 'v', 385],
          ['Netherlands, Rotterdam', 'Jet' ,             2,      100000,      'Dorpsstraat',  'Rotterdam', new Date(2014,  7,  7), new Date(2015,  2, 16), 'v', 964],
          ['Netherlands, Rotterdam', 'Teun',             1,       85670,       'Kerkstraat',  'Rotterdam', new Date(2014,  3, 22), new Date(2016, 11, 12), 'm', 356],
      ['Netherlands, Utrecht', 'Gijs',             1,       53400,   'Stationsstraat',    'Utrecht', new Date(2014,  3, 22), new Date(2016,  6, 18), 'm', 356],
            ['Netherlands, Utrecht', 'Does',             1,       77200,         'Vreeburg',    'Utrecht', new Date(2014,  3, 22), new Date(2016,  8,  8), 'm', 768],
             ['Netherlands',         'Does1',             0,           0,       'Amsterdam',  'Nederland', new Date(2014,  3, 22), new Date(2016,  8,  8), '', 467],
             ['Netherlands',         'Does2',             0,           0,       'Rotterdam',  'Nederland', new Date(2014,  3, 22), new Date(2016,  8,  8), '', 563],
             ['Netherlands',         'Does3',             0,           0,         'Utrecht',  'Nederland', new Date(2014,  3, 22), new Date(2016,  8,  8), '', 467],
             ['Netherlands',         'Does4',             0,           0,       'Nederland',         null, new Date(2014,  3, 22), new Date(2016,  8,  8), '', 963]
        ]);
  
        // Create a dashboard.
        var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard_div'));
  
        // Create a range slider, passing some options
        var donutRangeSlider = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
          'controlType': 'NumberRangeFilter',
          'containerId': 'filter_div',
          'options': {
            'filterColumnLabel': 'Leningdelen'
          }
        });

var tableE = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    'chartType': 'Table',
          'containerId': 'tableE_div',
    'view': {'rows'   : data.getFilteredRows([{column: 2, minValue: 1}])},
          'options': {
      'showRowNumber': 'true',
            'width': '100%',
            'height': '33%',
          }
  });
  
        // Create a pie chart, passing some options
        var pieChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
          'chartType': 'PieChart',
          'containerId': 'chart_div',
    'view': {'columns': [1, 2], 
                   'rows'   : data.getFilteredRows([{column: 2, minValue: 1}])},
          'options': {
            'width': 400,
            'height': 300,
            'pieSliceText': 'value',
            'legend': 'right'
          }
        });

          // Create a bar chart, passing some options
        var barChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
          'chartType': 'BarChart',
          'containerId': 'chartB_div',
    'view': {'columns': [1, 2], 
                   'rows'   : data.getFilteredRows([{column: 2, minValue: 1}])},
          'options': {
            'width': 500,
            'height': 300,
            'legend': 'right'
          }
        });
  
        // Establish dependencies, declaring that 'filter' drives 'pieChart',
        // so that the pie chart will only display entries that are let through
        // given the chosen slider range.
        dashboard.bind(donutRangeSlider, [tableE, pieChart, barChart]);

        // Draw the dashboard.
        dashboard.draw(data);
      }
   
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!--Div that will hold the dashboard-->
    <div id="dashboard_div">
 <table class="columns">
      <tr>
        <td><div id="filter_div" style="border: 1px solid #ccc"></div></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td><div id="chart_div" style="border: 1px solid #ccc"></div></td>
        <td><div id="chartB_div" style="border: 1px solid #ccc"></div></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <table>
   <tr>
       <td><div id="tableE_div" style="border: 1px solid #ccc"></div></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Hi,
I am trying to make a dashboard with many differend graphs, but I cannot solve the issue 'Invalid row index 5. Should be in the range [0-4].' 
Now I have a very simple dashboard, it works when I use only the data columns the 2 simple graphs need. But I want more graphs with other columns. When I add more columns to the data, the error pops up. I think I need a ready Listener somewhere in the code, but I tried so many times using the answeres for others, but without success.
So will you please complete my code with a ready listener so the error will be solved? Thanks !

Comment: _So will you please complete my code_ ... SO is not a free code writing service. Please take the [tour] and also read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a `'ready'` listener will not resolve the problem

the problem stems from...

```
'rows'   : data.getFilteredRows([{column: 2, minValue: 1}])}
```

once the dashboard is drawn and the filter value changes,
there are rows that exist in the `data`, that do not exist in the `dashboard`

so `getFilteredRows` is returning more rows than the dashboard has access to

thus, the error is thrown --> `Invalid row index`

to correct, just use an overall DataView to draw the dashboard

```
var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
view.setRows(data.getFilteredRows([{column: 2, minValue: 1}]));

dashboard.draw(view);
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart', 'controls', 'table']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawDashboard);
function drawDashboard() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['geo_Stad',               'Name', 'Leningdelen', 'Hypotheek',           'Straat', 'Woonplaats',          'Datum_start',          'Datum_eind', 'Mv', 'looptijd'],
    ['Netherlands, Amsterdam', 'Aap' ,             5,      500000,     'Kalverstraat',  'Amsterdam', new Date(2014,  3, 22), new Date(2016,  2, 28), 'm', 123],
    ['Netherlands, Rotterdam', 'Noot',             1,       70000,       'Beursplein',  'Rotterdam', new Date(2014, 10, 11), new Date(2017,  3, 20), 'm', 234],
    ['Netherlands, Rotterdam', 'Mies',             3,      300000,    'Stationsplein',  'Rotterdam', new Date(2013, 10,  1), new Date(2013, 12, 23), 'v', 564],
    ['Netherlands, Amsterdam', 'Wim' ,             2,      222222,      'Dorpsstraat',  'Amsterdam', new Date(2010,  1,  2), new Date(2016, 10, 23), 'm', 456],
    ['Netherlands, Amsterdam', 'Zus' ,             7,      600000,    'Stationsplein',  'Amsterdam', new Date(2007,  5, 22), new Date(2009,  2,  2), 'v', 385],
    ['Netherlands, Rotterdam', 'Jet' ,             2,      100000,      'Dorpsstraat',  'Rotterdam', new Date(2014,  7,  7), new Date(2015,  2, 16), 'v', 964],
    ['Netherlands, Rotterdam', 'Teun',             1,       85670,       'Kerkstraat',  'Rotterdam', new Date(2014,  3, 22), new Date(2016, 11, 12), 'm', 356],
    ['Netherlands, Utrecht', 'Gijs',             1,       53400,   'Stationsstraat',    'Utrecht', new Date(2014,  3, 22), new Date(2016,  6, 18), 'm', 356],
    ['Netherlands, Utrecht', 'Does',             1,       77200,         'Vreeburg',    'Utrecht', new Date(2014,  3, 22), new Date(2016,  8,  8), 'm', 768],
    ['Netherlands',         'Does1',             0,           0,       'Amsterdam',  'Nederland', new Date(2014,  3, 22), new Date(2016,  8,  8), '', 467],
    ['Netherlands',         'Does2',             0,           0,       'Rotterdam',  'Nederland', new Date(2014,  3, 22), new Date(2016,  8,  8), '', 563],
    ['Netherlands',         'Does3',             0,           0,         'Utrecht',  'Nederland', new Date(2014,  3, 22), new Date(2016,  8,  8), '', 467],
    ['Netherlands',         'Does4',             0,           0,       'Nederland',         null, new Date(2014,  3, 22), new Date(2016,  8,  8), '', 963]
  ]);

  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setRows(data.getFilteredRows([{column: 2, minValue: 1}]));

  var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard_div'));

  var donutRangeSlider = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    'controlType': 'NumberRangeFilter',
    'containerId': 'filter_div',
    'options': {
      'filterColumnLabel': 'Leningdelen'
    }
  });

  var tableE = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    'chartType': 'Table',
    'containerId': 'tableE_div',
    'options': {
      'showRowNumber': 'true',
      'width': '100%',
      'height': '33%',
    }
  });

  var pieChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    'chartType': 'PieChart',
    'containerId': 'chart_div',
    'view': {
      'columns': [1, 2]
    },
    'options': {
      'width': 400,
      'height': 300,
      'pieSliceText': 'value',
      'legend': 'right'
    }
  });

  var barChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    'chartType': 'BarChart',
    'containerId': 'chartB_div',
    'view': {
      'columns': [1, 2]
    },
    'options': {
      'width': 500,
      'height': 300,
      'legend': 'right'
    }
  });

  dashboard.bind(donutRangeSlider, [tableE, pieChart, barChart]);
  dashboard.draw(view);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="dashboard_div">
  <table class="columns">
    <tr>
      <td><div id="filter_div" style="border: 1px solid #ccc"></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><div id="chart_div" style="border: 1px solid #ccc"></div></td>
      <td><div id="chartB_div" style="border: 1px solid #ccc"></div></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><div id="tableE_div" style="border: 1px solid #ccc"></div></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi WhiteHat, You are my hero of the day !!! Thank you so much. It works and I understand what you have changed. I can't wait to implement my other ideas to the dashboard. :)